# Divisors of factorials

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $k$ a positive integer. Let $d$ be the smallest positive integer such that $p^k$ divides $d!$. It is true that $d$ is necessarily a multiple of $p$?

Comment: Moreover, $k \leq p \implies pk|d$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $d!$ is this number. Then $(d-1)!$ is not. Since $p^k$ does not divide $(d-1)!$ but it divides $d! = d \cdot (d-1)!$, then $p$ must divide $d$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** If $p$ does not divide $d$, then $(d-1)!$ would also be divisible by $p$ since it has the same number of prime factors $p$ as $d!$ has.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If it didn't then $d!$ would have the same power of $p$ in its factorisation as $(d-1)!$ has, thus $p^k | (d-1)!$ contradicting the minimality.